# How to get rid of full screen video translucency?

Tags: macos, video, fullscreen

I recently noticed that whenever I watch a video in full screen on the Mac, the video has a certain level of translucency showing the contents of the window or the desktop behind it.

This occurs with all YouTube videos I open in the browser as well as VLC Player. I haven't tested with every other video player I have yet. I haven't tested what happens with multiple monitors yet either.

How can I get rid of this translucency?

Comment: are you using the html player on youtube or just the flash player, and what format are the videos in vlc for instance?

Comment: Flash player on YouTube from within Safari - nothing changes with OS X and Safari updates to the latest version. I see the windows and icons translucently behind the video. The problem occurs regardless of the video format (tested with mov, avi, mkv, mp4).